# Workflow for modifying existing crud scaffolded model, views & controllers

Tags: yii, workflow

I am in the process of learning Yii framework. I have always previously built plugins in wordpress and I have never used a PHP MVC framework before.

- Assuming I have designed my database
- Used Yiic shell - console to model the db and create crud classes etc.
- Modified the controllers and views to my custom requirements.

Now the client requirements change and an extra field is required in the database.

- I modify the database to add for example "tel2" field to the customer table.

Do I need to update the model, view and controller manually to incorporate these changes or do I save customisations then get Yiic shell to re-scaffold the model, view & controller, then re-write the customisations manually?

I am sure that I can do either, but is there an easier way / is there a way in which you all work which makes your lives easier?

Comment: Update the existing code manually. Rebuilding the scaffold and your customizations would take much longer.

Answer (score 5):

This was a question on my mind also when I began Yii.

The simple answer to it is you dont have to change everything. The Gii module is a really powerful feature of Yii and after making the CRUD and the model after a DB table, and if you have your own custom functions and methods and then you decide that you need to alter a table and add a new column to it, all you need to do remake the model in gii and it shall show the the modified code in a seperate link tagged as "**diff**".

Gii only generates the code, it does not overwrite it.

Now all you need to do is open up the "diff" make sure that you do not overwrite the code as there would be an overwrite button as well. After you check out the "diff" code, it shall show the new columns and the new properties highlighted, now all you need to do is copy the requisite changed code into your original code.

This way, you can do as many changes as you want with everything remaining intact.

There is also another method. You can use a base class and extend all your code into another file. This way, all you need to do is change the base model and everything still remains intact.

[image: dii image]

I think this should have answered your question.

Regards,

Comment: Looks very promising. I will have a play... Thank you. Assuming that this works. Will vote your answer if it does. Thanks again.

Comment: It does, am using this method :) But am glad to be of help!

Comment: I think if this method did help you, you may mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You should look at `gii` as a tool that gets you started quickly. But once you created your models and maybe CRUDs you can usually forget about it. Your project code evolves and - if it's not a very simply project - you will have a lot of manual changes to the auto generated code anyway.

So every time you touch your DB you will update the related files. Often this only involves to add a new attribute rule in `rules()` in your model, and adding another input field to the form view.